# Can there be more format specifiers or order can be different than arguments in a C printf statement?

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
int a =9;
float b = 1.23;
double c = 6.2396734679;

printf("%d %f %e",b,a);

return 0;
}
```

How is the output -> 9 1.230000 1.230000e+00 ??

The order of arguments is not correct + Can there be less arguments than format specifiers?

Comment: Definition of "can" is unclear, but this code invokes *undefined behavior*.

Comment: "_Can there be more format specifiers [...] than arguments in a C printf statement?"_ - Obviously, but it has undefined behavior.

Comment: Mismatching format specifier and argument types, or missing arguments for a format specifier, both leads to *undefined behavior*.

Comment: What output do you expect if there is a missing argument?

Comment: The order cannot be different. By definition (cf. documentation) the first format specifier must match the first argument, the second format specifier must match the second argument etc.

Comment: It is a very bad idea, and just about guaranteed not to work, if you have fewer actual arguments than format specifiers.  It's just about no problem if you have more actual arguments than format specifiers (although a good compiler will warn about this).  In straight C, the actual arguments must be in the same order as the format specifiers.  There are extensions (I believe standardized by POSIX) that allow you to explicitly number the format specifiers to indicate which actual argument they go with, so that they don't have to be in the same order.

Comment: The fact that you *seemed* to get semi-correct output, even though you were missing an argument and the other two were out of order, is somewhat interesting, but it doesn't prove anything, other than that the actual mechanisms used for passing variable-length argument lists can be surprising, and different than what you might expect.  (There are more details about this in [Eric's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75792147#75792226).)

Comment: Note that POSIX [`fprintf()`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fprintf.html) has a mechanism such that, if you are careful enough, you can reorder the appearance of data in the output using the notations like `%3$*1$.*1$` to identify arguments to the function via the `n$`.  There are restrictions on that — and you either use `n$` everywhere or nowhere in a format string.  However, this can help with I18N/L10N efforts.

Answer (score 3):

From the C11 standard:

> If there are insufficient arguments for the format, the behavior is
> undefined. If the format is exhausted while arguments remain, the
> excess arguments are evaluated (as always) but are otherwise ignored.
>
> ...
>
> If any argument is not the correct type for the corresponding
> conversion specification, the behavior is undefined.

- It is undefined behaviour if the number of format specifiers exceed the number of arguments provided.
- If excess arguments are provided, and the format string is exhausted, the arguments are simply ignored, and there's no undefined behaviour involved.
- The order shall not be different. The first format specifier must match the first argument provided, the second format specifier should match the second argument provided, and so on. If any argument is not the correct type for the corresponding conversion specification, the behavior is undefined.

Answer (score 2):

> Can there be more format specifiers or order can be different than arguments in a C printf statement?

Yes, you can do this, and the C standard does not define the behavior of the program when you do, so it is a bad idea and you should not expect it to work.

In many C implementations, the first few integer arguments are passed in the general processor registers, and the first few floating-point arguments are passed in floating-point registers. So a called routine will look for its integer arguments in the general registers (say numbers `r8`, `r9`, and `r10`) and will look for its floating-point arguments in the floating-point registers (say `f4`, `f5`, and `f6`).  Because of this, if you swap integer and floating-point arguments, the routine will still look for and find integer arguments in the general registers and floating-point arguments in the floating-point registers. For example, both `foo(1, 2, 3., 4.)` and `foo(1, 3., 2, 4.)` will put the integer values 1 and 2 in the first two general processor registers used for arguments and the floating-point values 3 and 4 in the first two floating-point registers used for arguments.

You should know about this behavior because it is useful for debugging purposes and for understanding how computers work, but you should not rely on it. When optimization is enabled in the compiler, advanced transformations may break this behavior.

Some C implementations do have features for listing the arguments in a format string in a different order than they appear in the function call, using additional characters in each conversion specification (the string with `%` that tells `printf` what to do besides echoing literal characters).

Comment: adding emphais: **but you MUST not rely on it.**

Comment: @SouravGhosh: You may rely on it: There is no law or other requirement imposed on people in general, or even programmers in general, that they may not rely on undefined behavior. It is a bad idea, but it is not something they are prohibited from doing, so saying they “must not” do it is false. I am aware you may wish to discourage such behavior, but I prefer to stick to the truth.